# Delete records from table how regenerate id for deleted row in the table using Hibernate(HQL)

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I have a table. A record from that table gets deleted (suppose id 1). How can I Insert a new record with the same id using hibernate? (right now I am using  generated type auto )

Is there any alternate solution for it instead of creating getter and setter for id?

Comment: Simply: no. You should keep track of existing IDs to generate new by your own. ID gaps won't be filled by Hibernate nor DBMS.

Comment: Clarified the question. It was hard to understand what is being asked.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, in SGBD, you use a sequence that generates a new unique id on demand.
When there is a delete, you generally don't care about reusing the freed slot. If you need to do it, it has to be with a custom development, by keeping a pool of *available* ids. This means you need to recycle ids from the deleted entities and manage concurrency accesses to it in order to keep unicity. This pool has to be persisted too.
All this has a cost, in complexity and performance.

There are several resources if you want to implement a custom id generator, like [this one](http://supportmycode.com/2014/08/22/custom-id-generator-in-hibernate/), but you will need to implement the recycling of ids strategy which is certainly more complex and may be not easy to hook in hibernate when there is a delete.